# how do I make valid <li> clickable when it contains 3 lines of text, including h3 tag?

Tags: css

I want to make my entire `li` clickable.
If I only had one line of text, I would simply set `a { display: block; height: 100% }`.

But sine I'm using a `h3` tag, I can't wrap the `<a>` tag around the `h3` tag (invalid html markup).

How can I solve this in a "simple and clean" way?

Here is an example code:

```
<li>
  <div>Some text</div>
  <h3> some header </h3>
  <div> some more text </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping an `a` tag around an `h3` tag is not invalid if you are using an [html5 doctype](http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/).